# Uncaught TypeError from generated JavaScript elements

Tags: javascript, html, runtime-error

I'm generating a dynamic list of from/inputs and buttons from JSON. The button triggers a JavaScript function that reads the current content of the input in a form. However when the button is clicked I get the following error code *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined*.
This tells me there are no elements in the form but I don't know why. Tryed 0-3 just to make sure.
Length also return undefined. I am able to edit the innerHTML of the form.

A striped down code I'm trying to get a value from.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body onload="gen_form()">
<div id="connectResult"></div>

<p id="demo">RESULT HERE</p> 

<script>
const connect_result = document.getElementById("connectResult");

function gen_form(){
    var div = document.createElement("DIV");
    div.setAttribute("id", "div0");
    div.innerHTML += "sometxt<br/>";

    var form1 = document.createElement("FROM");
    form1.setAttribute("id", 'form_sometxt2_0');

    var input1 = document.createElement("input");
    input1.setAttribute("type",'text');
    input1.setAttribute("name",'textbox');

    form1.appendChild(input1);
    div.appendChild(form1);

    var btn4 = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    btn4.setAttribute("id", 'WRITE_sometxt2_0');
    btn4.innerHTML = 'WRITE';
    btn4.setAttribute("onclick", "myFunction(this)");

    div.appendChild(btn4);
    connect_result.appendChild(div);
}

function myFunction(param) {
  var text = document.getElementById("form_sometxt2_0").elements[0].value + "<br>";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}

</script>
</html>
```

The following does exactly what I want but it is static. The above is based off this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="frm1">
  <input type="text">
</form>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo">RESULT HERE</p> 

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var text = document.getElementById("frm1").elements[0].value + "<br>";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>
</html>
```

My question is: What is the difference between these two code snippets and how do I fix said error?

I would prefer not to use a submit input as there will be a second button that edits the contents of the input value.

PS: I'm fairly new to JavaScript and its terminology.

Using Chrome as my debugger.

Comment: `var form1 = document.createElement("FROM");` it should be `FORM` shouldn't it ?

Comment: @Dominik Matis yes thx. 4am coding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tipo error.[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57562511/uncaught-typeerror-from-generated-javascript-elements?noredirect=1#comment101586725_57562511)

```
var form1 = document.createElement("FROM");
```

should be:

```
var form1 = document.createElement("FORM");
```